# how to detect if an HTML input content is updated

Tags: javascript, html

I am making this project requires a function that update product information. there is a HTML form with many inputs such as text box and etc, and this form is response for the "Update" function, so when click on update button, all the input content will be write into database. Because the tons of "information" are involved in the form, so I want to find out if its possible that I only track the html input which has been edited.

for example, when I click on the submit button, there is only one text box content has been changes, then I only need to process the text from that specific text box and ignore the rest of form(since there weren't edited).

any suggestion? solution for this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far? Please post any code you might have so far.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Provide an effort of your own and explain what it is that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be based on:

1. at dom ready save each input value as data attribute
2. before submit check which input changed

```js
function saveOrigValues() {
    document.querySelectorAll('form input:not([type="submit"])').forEach(function(ele) {
        switch (ele.type.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'text':
                ele.dataset.origValue = ele.value;
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                ele.dataset.origValue = ele.checked;
                break;
        }
    });
}
function getChangedValues() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form input:not([type="submit"])')).reduce(function(a, ele) {
        var currValue = '';
        switch (ele.type.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'text':
                currValue = ele.value;
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                currValue = ele.checked.toString();
                break;
        }
        if (ele.dataset.origValue != undefined && ele.dataset.origValue != currValue) {
            a.push({name: ele.name, value: currValue});
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
}

// save original values at dom ready....
saveOrigValues();

document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // on submit find changed values....
    e.preventDefault();
    var changedValues = getChangedValues();
    
    console.log('Changed values are (name / value): ' + JSON.stringify(changedValues));
})
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="ele1" type="text" value="1">
    <input name="ele2" type="checkbox">c1
    <input name="ele3" type="checkbox">c2
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I just tried out your suggestion,I triggered an alert in the "document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e)..."  function, and I do got the two text boxes I just edited value. and I got the result like this "[object HTMLInputElement]". Do you have an accurate answer of what is the result that I got from the function, a list of elements? this is my thoughts.  Then, I need to get the value from each of them and need to keep tracking which specific HTML elements is changed, because I need to create JSON object next step, would you offer more help? THANKS!!!

Comment: @LevittShanHe Snippet updated. Now **getChangedValues** returns an array of changed name/value couples

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what kind of request your api is expecting.

Since you say you'd like to reduce the amount of information thats being updated, I will assume your api allows for such updates.

Lets say your api accepts a request like the following (where each property is can be omitted):

**[PUT]** **/person/id**

```
{
   name: "e.g. some name",
   age: "e.g. some age"
}
```

Then you could build the request object elegantly by adding the respective attribute in each `onchange` event.

It would look like this:

1.Declare a global request object.

```
var request = {}
```

2.Write a function that updates the request object via key:value

```
function AppendToRequest(key, value){ 
    request[key] = value
}
```

3.Attach this function to each input form with the key that the api expects:

```
<input id="name" ... onchange="(event) => AppendToRequest('name', event.target.value)" />
<input id="age" ... onchange="(event) => AppendToRequest('age', event.target.value)" />
```

4.After hitting up the api make sure to reset the request object for later updates.

```
request = {}
```